# Does a store see my email address when I pay with Google Pay (NFC)

Tags: google-account, nfc, google-pay

Can a store see an email address associated with my Google account (a card has been added to) when I pay with Google Pay via NFC?

Answer (score 2):

Google Pay transmits credit card number(s) to the merchant terminal, I don't think the payment NFC standard even has the possibility to transmit an e-mail address (no data field for that).

According to the "Detailed Google Pay transaction process in stores" this data is transmitted from the phone to the payment terminal:

> 2. Merchant receives token: When the customer taps their device on an NFC-enabled terminal at the store’s point-of-sale, the device sends the token, token expiry date, and cryptogram to the terminal via the NFC protocol.

https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/answer/6345242?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdetailed-google-pay-transaction-process-in-stores

The data is processed then by the "Acquirer" and "TSP" both financial companies. In the end the merchant respectively the used terminal just gets a success or failure response but no customer data.